# Real Time Operating Systems for Embedded Systems -> Good Starting books

Tags: embedded, operating-system, rtos

I have worked extensively on AVR microcontrollers. I haven't had a proper OS course at UNI..not from a CS branch, but I want a book that gives me generic OS concepts as well as RTOS concepts for embedded systems. Any suggestion?. Something that details a particular OS like TinyOS or FemtoOS would be nice, but I want something with API based examples/codes as well.

Any suggestions  ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At least 3 (well, 4) books come to mind immediately:

- [MicroC OS II: The Real Time Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578201039), and [the follow-up, for uC/OS-III](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0982337531)
- The [FreeRTOS book(s)](http://www.freertos.org/shop/books-ebooks-manuals-c-32.html)
- Miro Samek's [book on the Quantum Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750687061), which goes into great depth on concepts like multitasking, preemption, and a run-to-completion kernel called the Quantum Kernel

Comment: I agree on all three of the above mentioned books. To understand non-realtime operating systems I recommend Andrew Tanenbaums book on "Modern Operating Systems" (0136006639) and "Linux Device Drivers", which is available online for free at http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxdrive3/book/index.csp

Comment: Miro Samek's book is not for beginners. As the author, I just don't want anybody to get disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

I've found David Simon's [Embedded Software Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161569X) to be very useful.  It provides a great high-level intro to RTOS architectures such as round-robin, round-robin with interrupts, and full-blown RTOS architecture.  Also, as mentioned previously, Tanenbaum's book is fantastic for a more in-depth treatment of OS concepts in general.

Mateja

Comment: How would you rate this book 


Real-Time Concepts for Embedded Systems 
by Qing Li and Carolyn Yao   


I think it covers both generic OS as well as embedded OS concepts, with VxWorks API , which AFAIK is used pretty widely.